# need the URL as key values in the python API JSON response

Tags: python

i have a simple python script i found it in google what i want is how can i get the URL in the response

```
  url= 'http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json'
  response=requests.get(url)
  print(response.json())
```

BElow is the response however i need the URL in the response as key value

{'message': 'success', 'people': [{'name': 'Kjell Lindgren', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Bob Hines', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Samantha Cristoforetti', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Jessica Watkins', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Cai Xuzhe', 'craft': 'Tiangong'}, {'name': 'Chen Dong', 'craft': 'Tiangong'}, {'name': 'Liu Yang', 'craft': 'Tiangong'}, {'name': 'Sergey Prokopyev', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Dmitry Petelin', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Frank Rubio', 'craft': 'ISS'}], 'number': 10}

Answer (score 0):

You can add it this way:

```
new_response = json.loads(response.json())
new_response['url'] = 'http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json'
```